# Zalando Rest API

Tags: rest, postman

Need help regarding working link of zalando. 
Searched nearly for whole day, but got only these links which are dead
Demo App: 
https://github.com/zalando/shop-api-demo/
Swagger based API endpoint documentation: https://api.zalando.com/swagger/index.html

Can anyone please guide me how i can access zalando dummy marketplace for building rest api for having connection, then fetching product and updating like-wise.

Is this the correct way nowdays?
https://partnerportal.zalando.com/support/solutions/articles/15000024320-how-to-integrate-via-zfs-apis

This guideline shows how to do, but does not provide working zalando link
https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#_zalando_restful_api_and_event_scheme_guidelines

DataFire for building and integrating api?
https://any-api.com/zalando_com/zalando_com/docs/_categories_key_/GET

Comment: Any success? Cannot get Zalando API to work. Just get "Not found because of proxy error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.zalando.com api.zalando.com:443" error 404. From https://any-api.com/zalando_com/zalando_com/console/_brands/GET

Comment: Any luck? Someone solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are looking for an official API (endpoints) released from Zalando, I have to disappoint you. Zalando (Shop) is (officially) not meant to be integrated with 3rd parties for browsing and shopping @ Zalando, or worse, for reselling on 3rd party clients.

That being said, the last [link you shared](https://any-api.com/zalando_com/zalando_com/docs/_categories_key_/GET) is basically somebody's homework - a well crawled public API definition that is used by the official Zalando clients, that obviously has to stay public. And of course, there are many bots and fishy 3rd party clients, that use this public API.

Zalando is not offering dropshipping, AFAIK, and AFAIK this is not even ever to be planned. So if you wanted to get official API specs with all the endpoints to build your own client, you have to rely on that [AnyAPI spec](https://any-api.com/zalando_com/zalando_com/docs/_categories_key_/GET) or do your own homework :-). However, be aware that any successful result is to be considered unofficial (I am not certain about legality).

The Partner API spec with endpoints is only available to Zalando's registered partners. The [PartnerPortal site you linked](https://partnerportal.zalando.com/support/solutions/articles/15000024320-how-to-integrate-via-zfs-apis) is a portal for such registered partners. To become a partner, you need to be either a producer or a retailer and willing to make business with Zalando or at Zalando as a platform, and given that Zalando, too, wants to make business with you :-).

Funnily enough, the [Rest API Guidelines](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#_zalando_restful_api_and_event_scheme_guidelines) are not meant to provide any links or endpoints of Zalando's APIs. These are simply guidelines built by top Zalando engineers strictly following the [HTTP Semantics RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110) and extending upon this. It is used internally by Zalando engineers as guidelines that must be followed when building any Zalando API, be it internal or public.